# Classic ASP - Converting a script to use parameters causing issues

Tags: sql, asp-classic

I have a very large search script which was not parameterized until now (although semi-protected by a regular expression function and wasn't open to public), but having just converted it, I've run in to some issues with the way I used to get the number of records.

This is an example of my script, before being parameterized:

```
selectClause = "SELECT column FROM table "
whereClause = "WHERE something = 'something' "

If something = "someCondition" Then
whereClause = whereClause & "AND something = '"&input&"' "
End If

If somethingElse = "someOtherCondition" Then
whereClause = whereClause & "AND somethingElse = '"&input&"' "
End If

' ... plus loads more conditional statements...

orderClause = "ORDER BY something DESC "

' get the total number of records, which is now what I am stuck on ////

SQL = " SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM ("&selectClause & whereClause&") AS Q1; "
Set rs = Conn.Execute(SQL)
If NOT rs.EOF Then
Session("record-count") = rs.Fields("totalRecords")
End If
rs.Close

' calculate paging and limitClause

... some code
limitClause = limit 0, 20 ' example

' build query

SQL = selectClause & whereClause & orderClause & limitClause

Conn.Execute(SQL)
```

Apart from being open to an attack, this worked fine. So I started to convert it, using parameters, but now I can't work out how to get the total count without having to write the whole search query again, which is 30 times the length of my example (above). Hopefully my code below will explain my situation better.

```
selectClause = "SELECT column FROM table "
whereClause = "WHERE something = 'something' "

If something = "someCondition" Then
whereClause = whereClause & "AND something = ? "
Set newParameter = cmdConn.CreateParameter("@blah1", ad_varChar, ad_ParamInput, Len(input), Replace(input,"'","\'"))
cmdConn.Parameters.Append newParameter
End If

If somethingElse = "someOtherCondition" Then
whereClause = whereClause & "AND somethingElse = ? "
Set newParameter = cmdConn.CreateParameter("@blah2", ad_varChar, ad_ParamInput, Len(input), Replace(input,"'","\'"))
cmdConn.Parameters.Append newParameter
End If

orderClause = "ORDER BY something DESC "

' but now the whereClause contains ?'s which cannot be used here, which has confused me on how I should be getting the new count.
' /////////////////////////////
SQL = " SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM ("&selectClause & whereClause&") AS Q1; "
Set rs = Conn.Execute(SQL)
If NOT rs.EOF Then
Session("record-count") = rs.Fields("totalRecords")
End If
rs.Close
' /////////////////////////////

' calculate paging and limitClause

... some code
limitClause = "limit x, y;"

' build query

SQL = selectClause & whereClause & orderClause & limitClause

cmdConn.CommandText = SQL
```

As you can see, I cannot use the count method I used before because the where clause contains ?'s which means that particular count query needs its own parameter collection. Can anybody suggest how I can now get my count without having to duplicate this huge query?

At a guess, I would probably create another command object `cmdConn2` and where I've set a  parameter, set another one the same but as `cmdConn2`, which could then be used for the count query, but my guesses aren't always the best method.

Any help always greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So essentially everything except the `select` and `order by` clauses is going to be identical for both queries.

One answer would therefore be:

- Move everything except the `select` and `order by` clauses into a subroutine.
- Set the `select` clause to be `select column from table`, call the subroutine for the common processing, then set the `order by` clause appropriately and execute the SQL.
- Then set the `select` clause to be `select count(*) from table`, call the subroutine for the common processing, then execute the SQL (no `order by` clause).

Alternatively, can you use anything like the [ADO RecordSet RecordCount property](http://classicasp.aspfaq.com/general/why-does-recordcount-return-as-1.html) from the result of the first query, to obtain the number of records returned?